# Menu is inflated at the bottom of the screen (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, menu, xamarin.android

I have a NoActionBar theme with an ImageButton button that acts as the menu button, which calls `OpenOptionsMenu()` method. Now the problem is, the menu is rendered at the bottom center of the screen and not below the button that triggered it.

I have did research (googled a lot) but nothing that i tried worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to go for a [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#PopupMenu) instead.

Comment: I went ahead and tried this option which looks promising but i'm getting exception when clicking the imagebutton "Could not find method showPopup(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute". I did just like in the example (I only added the public method showPopup (modified it a bit to match xamarin) and added the onClick attr in the xml.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/popup-menu